# update table data dynamically

Tags: java, mysql

I want to update the category and english column of the field at the same time dynamically

I am trying to update the table data but this code is not working.

```
String query6 = "UPDATE `tagger`.`postag` SET category='"+"sqll"+" and english='"+"sql"+"";
psmt1 = conn2.prepareStatement(query6);
psmt1.setString(1,sql);
psmt1.setString(2,sqll);
psmt1.executeUpdate(query6);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be clear on what is the problem that you are facing...

Comment: could you give us the structure of the table please?
also; you're going to update the entire table and overwrite those field values of every row in the table with what you give this here, you need a where clause.

and if you're getting an error, please give us the stacktrace from the console if you don't understand it, you seem new here...

Comment: Try to run the query in the sql console of your database, once you have the perfect query then put in your java code...that way you wont have to run the program again at every minor change. Also as pythonian mentioned please provide error message/stacktrace while posting.

Comment: @pythonian29033: the statement is wrong, `AND` only makes sense within a `WHERE`/`HAVING` clause or as parameter for `JOIN` and friends.

Comment: @Philip thanks for telling me. . .but I don't need to know that, I think you've got the wrong person

Comment: @pythonian29033: I just wanted to point out that there is probably no problem in the table structure.  Given the fact that this post got 2 downvotes, this seems important IMHO.  There's no point in trying to solve more problems than the OP is asking...

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
String query6 = "UPDATE tagger.postag SET category=?, english=?";
```

(comma instead of `AND`, many RDBMS expect question marks for the arguments, others want `$1` and `$2` which would be `String query6 = "UPDATE tagger.postag SET category=$1, english=$2";`)

By the way, I **strongly** recommend you to not concatenate quoted strings.  It makes your code not look like a prepared statement and difficult to read.

Comment: String query6 = "UPDATE `tagger`.`postag` SET category=?, english=?";

Answer (score 0):

Why are you String concatination when you are using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?
`PreparedStatement` is simple just use `?` placeholder

> You must **supply values in place of the question mark(?) placeholders** (if there are any) before you can execute a PreparedStatement object. Do this by calling one of the setter methods defined in the PreparedStatement class.

```
String query6 = "UPDATE tagger.postag SET category=? and english=?";
                                                   ↑             ↑
psmt1 = conn2.prepareStatement(query6);
psmt1.setString(1,sql);
psmt1.setString(2,sqll);
psmt1.executeUpdate(query6);
```